# Child extract-text-webpack-plugin in console logging too many times

Tags: webpack, extract-text-plugin

I have an issue with this (the title) spamming my console.  I got called onto a project that I did not write and this was one of the issues one of the devs wanted fixed.

```
webpackConfig.plugins.push(
  new ExtractTextPlugin('components/[name]/css/[name].css', {
    allChunks: true,
  })
)
```

I've added

```
stats: {children: false}
```

and

```
children: false
```

inside where allChunks is and neither of them work.